# How to set minimum number of lines on uilabel

Tags: objective-c

can this be done? I have good reason for to use this somewhere. Adding text to meet quality standards....AND heres more, and more, and more and more, quality standards met....

```
some fake code var=nothing
```

Comment: Cal you tell us your reason? 'cause your question is kinda vague...

Comment: autolayout special case where xcode is basically not knowledgeable of cell height and features due to improper ios cell recycling; aka not something i can fix

Answer (score 1):

You could take the `lineHeight` of the `UIFont` that the label's using and make its frame's height that times three.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I needed to have a cell with a constant height, but the contents of a label could be shorter than what was needed to have it always have three lines.

I duplicated the label, set the contents to "1\n2\n3" to give it the three lines required, set it to hidden, and then gave it the top and bottom constraints of the label I wanted to have a consistent height.

Then I set the visible label top constraint to my placeholder and removed its bottom constraint.

Now the placeholder fixes the height at the required amount and the visible label will grow down (to the maximum of three lines) as needed while staying fixed to the top (and not centering verticaly if it doesn't have content for three lines).